# ios/swift - How to disable keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have a simple iOS app with two controllers. One of them holds a webview displaying a website. The website has its own keyboard which appears when editing html input fields. However, when trying to use one of these inputs iOS displays its own built in keyboard.

How to disable keyboard in iOS/swift from popping up in a single controller or within a web view?

Comment: Just worth a mention, I don't think this behaviour would be approved by apple in the AppStore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

///

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: That works. Is there a way to have the cursor still appearing at the edited field?